# Display information about hardware in Linux/Unix

Tags: linux, unix

I want to display information about my hardware, and there are three commands to do that:

```
dmesg
lshal
dmidecode
```

but I'm confused between these three commands.

So what is the difference among them?

Comment: There is some better options are being discussed in this [article](http://www.binarytides.com/linux-commands-hardware-info/). Read them and use them.

Comment: Maybe `lshw` is better? Also, lshal, dmidecode and lshw are Linux-specific. Unixes have much different tools (like `prtdiag` in Solaris)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest that you use `lshw`, a very helpful tool to list your hardware.  From its `man` page:

> `lshw`  is  a  small tool to extract detailed information on the hardware configuration of the machine. It can report exact memory configuration, firmware version, mainboard configuration, CPU version and speed, cache configuration, bus speed, etc. on DMI-capable x86 or IA-64 systems  and on some PowerPC machines (PowerMac G4 is known to work).

Comment: I know I answered this late, but if the answer works for you, it would be great if you accept it as the answer – so that other users can benefit from knowing that the answer works.  If you had any issues, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The **dmesg** command is used to write the kernel messages in Linux and other Unix-like operating systems to standard output.

From **man** pages:

**lshal** - list HAL devices

> lshal is a utility for displaying items in the HAL device database.
>   For more information about both the big picture and specific HAL
>   properties, refer to the HAL spec which can be found in
>   /usr/share/doc/hal-0.5.14/spec/hal-spec.html depending on the
>   distribution.

**dmidecode** - DMI Table Decoder

> dmidecode is a tool for dumping a computer's DMI (some say SMBIOS )
>   table contents in a human-readable format. This table contains a
>   description of the system's hardware components, as well as other
>   useful pieces of information such as serial numbers and BIOS revision.
>   Thanks to this table, you can retrieve this information without having
>   to probe for the actual hardware. While this is a good point in terms
>   of report speed and safeness, this also makes the presented
>   information possibly unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

The ***dmesg*** command is used to write the kernel messages in Linux and other Unix-like operating systems to standard output (which by default is the display screen).

***lshal*** is a utility for displaying items in the HAL device database.

***dmidecode*** is a tool for dumping a computer's DMI (some say SMBIOS ) table contents in a human-readable format. This table contains a description of the system's hardware components, as well as other useful pieces of information such as serial numbers and BIOS revision. Thanks to this table, you can retrieve this information without having to probe for the actual hardware. While this is a good point in terms of report speed and safeness, this also makes the presented information possibly unreliable.

I would suggest to go for "***dmesg***" and use the options as per you need to obtain information about the hardware on a system.
dmesg [options]